# How does the console works on codecademy.com/tryruby.org?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby

The websites I am talking about - [codecademy.com](http://www.codecademy.com/) and [tryruby.org](http://tryruby.org).

My guess would be that the console is a simple `div` with a key listeners "attached" to it. Whenever a user presses any key and submits it by pressing enter, the console just adds whatever he typed after the last letter in the `div` and "moves" the `>> [type here` part to last line of the `div`.

However, I'm not sure if that's so simple, so I would like to know what do other people think. I believe that it would be too inefficient - especially when we are talking about situation where the whole console is too stuffed with the text - adding any sign to the last line and moving the rest of the text up then would take too much time for browser to process.

Comment: FYI, [here's the JavaScript](http://www.tryruby.org/javascripts/mouseapp_2.js) for  the console part of http://www.tryruby.org/. [It's also on GitHub](https://github.com/Sophrinix/TryRuby/blob/master/public/javascripts/mouseapp_2.js), if you want to see its history.

Comment: Thanks, but it would take ages for me to find the way how it works by reading the code. That's why I asked this question here hoping that there is anyone who knows how is it done or knows alternative method to what I've described.

Comment: If someone else wants another javascript example
https://github.com/chrisdone/jquery-console
from the http://tryhaskell.org/  which was inspired by tryruby.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands are sent via AJAX to an actual Ruby interpreter, the explanation you provided is correct, but does not account for the fact that the commands provide any sensible results in the Ruby language.

Comment: I just wanted to know how does the command-line thing works. If my explanation was correct, then there is no need to keep this question opened anymore. Thanks.